# Simulate the effect of device back-light to image perception of humans

Tags: image, image-processing, image-manipulation

Even if we see the exact same image in a device (e.g. iPad), we perceive it different when the back-light is different. For example if we look at the following two images, they are both same image but the latter one has no back-light (disregard the reflections), and we perceive it different. My question is how can I simulate the effect of no back-light, without actually dimming it but playing with the original image? Maybe applying some kind of semi-transparent black mask?

**Full backlight**
[image]

**No backlight**
[image]

Comment: `can I simulate the effect... without actually dimming it, only adjusting the original image?` So for example... If you were doing this in Photoshop you would be using options like **levels**, **exposure**, **contrast**, **gamma** etc? Is that what you aim to do by code? 2-layer blending modes could be an option too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simulate it. Physically it's a very simple effect, and only your eyes make it look like a more complicated illusion.

It's just a combination of two layers:

- the photo (backlight)
- the reflection (no backlight image)

The reflection simply exists all the time. The backlight image is turned on or off. In terms of implementation these are additive layers (sum of pixel values).

Eyes only perceive backlight on/off as a complete change of the image, because the eyes adjust to overall brightness level of the screen.

If you're implementing that in code:

- make sure you use linear light colorspace for processing (remove gamma correction, process pixels, apply gamma correction).
- when displaying the image on screen, normalize brightness (since to display the effect on screen you have to have it brighter than the actual real-world effect, and you have lower dynamic range to work with).